# Java Iterator implementation causing compile errors

Tags: java, iterator

I'm unsure how to add Iterator code to my DLL class

i tried two approaches but i get compile errors in both cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DLL myList = new DLL() ;

...

public java.util.Iterator iterator()
(
    return new LRIterator() ;
)

private class LRIterator implements Iterator
{
 ...
}
...
```

compile error: `';' expected public java.util.Iterator iterator();`

other approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DLL myList = new DLL() ;
    ...
    Iterator itr = myList.iterator(); 
    while(itr.hasNext()) {

    Object element = itr.next(); 
    System.out.print(element + " ");
}
...
```

copile error: `cannot find symbol Iterator = myList.iterator();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to change `(` and `)` into `{` and `}` in the following snippet:

```
public java.util.Iterator iterator()
(
    return new LRIterator() ;
)
```

---

A few extra pointers.

- I suggest you don't use the *raw type* of `Iterator` and instead use `Iterator<T>` if your list contains elements of type `T`.
- I suggest you let your class which has the `iterator()` method implement the `Iterable<T>` interface. This allows users of your class to use it in for each loops for instance.

Comment: Deuh! I'm sorry for asking the question now... Thanks for the additional tips! – getting a new error: LRIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method remove()...any idea?